# Add transition to changin text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I have the below code to change the text on interval. I want to add a transition for opacity while changing the text. There are other answers which use fade in and out method of jquery but did not work with the given javascript code.

```js
var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
var inst = setInterval(change, 1000);

function change() {
  elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
  counter++;
  if (counter >= text.length) {
    counter = 0;
    // clearInterval(inst); // uncomment this if you want to stop refreshing after one cycle
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="changeText"></div>
```

Updated code

```
function change() {
      elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
      document.getElementById('s2main').style.opacity = 1;
      counter++;
      if (counter >= text.length) {
        counter = 0;
        // clearInterval(inst); // uncomment this if you want to stop refreshing after one cycle
      }
    }
```

added CSS

```
#changetext{
opacity:0;
transition: opacity 400ms
```

the transition only works for the first text and also transition takes 3s.

Comment: What is the intended behavior? What will be the opacity while changing the text, and after changing it?

Comment: First the opacity will be from 1 to 0 while changing t next text. @SinanYaman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another element as a container and change the container's opacity.
If you want to make one text fade into the next one, instead of fading out and in, then you could use more than 1 span elements here.

Also note, this is a rough code, not yet visually elegant, so you should tune the timings to your needs.

```js
var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];

var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
var elemContainer = document.getElementById("changeTextContainer");
var inst = setInterval(change, 1000);

function showText() {
    elemContainer.style.opacity = 1;
}
function change() {
    elemContainer.style.opacity = 0;
    elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
    setTimeout (showText, 500);
    counter++;
    if (counter >= text.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

```css
#changeTextContainer {
    transition: opacity 400ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="changeTextContainer"><span id="changeText"></span></div>
```

Comment: The code provided works but I am unable to set a time for a smooth transition between the two texts. What parameter will be changed in what condition? my text change time is ```3000ms```. the transition looks like jumping.

Comment: solved by making initial opacity to 1 and function opacity to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use css transitions:

```
#changeText {
    transition: opacity 400ms;
}
```

You can then set the opacity value with JS, or even remove/ add different classes to speed up or remove the effect.

Since you tagged jQuery but dont seem to use any, jQuery has inbuilt fade animations:

```
$('#changeText').finish().fadeTo(300, 0, function() {
    // do stuff
    // fade back in again
    $('#changeText').finish().fadeTo(300, 1);
});
```

Comment: I have updated the code but did not work as thought

Comment: @tru_shar yes it does, but you dont set the opacity back to 0. Also, make sure your interval is bigger than 2x the css transition

Comment: okay so I removed the ```opacity:0``` from the CSS. and also removed ```document.getElementById('s2main').style.opacity = 1;
```. It makes no difference while changing. still changes without transition.